# Why CSP doesn't allow to load script though meta is configured in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, content-security-policy

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC app and want to use js script. I've added it to my `_Layout` page and it works fine. Then I wanted to add reCaptcha to my app. So I linked the script and it's not rendered and I get this error:

> Refused to load the script 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

So I added meta to my `_Layout.cshtml` file like this

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src data: 'self'; default-src 'self'; script-src * data: https://www.google.com/ 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">
```

But I still get the same error though the docs tells that if `script-src-elem` is not present then `script-src` will be used. But for some reason it is not used though is is configured. What can be the issue?

PS: I also tried to configure `script-src-elem` but it didn't work either.

Update: i also have troubles with images. Trying to configure CSP like that `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; img-src data:;" />` results in:

> Refused to load the image '' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src data:"

But using this policy trying to add data: image using javascript results in

> Refused to load the image 'data:image/jpeg;base64,*' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

So this policy is used in first case and ignored in the second one

Comment: Please also post the error message for "also tried to configure script-src-elem but it didn't work either.". (edit question please)

Comment: the message is just the same. it seems to me that both script-src and script-src-elem are ignored

Comment: You need to see this [article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp).

Comment: This article is really useful but it hasn't solved my problem as my policy is configured correctly according to this article and it is still being ignored

Answer (score 1):

Finally i solved it. My project was based on identityserver4 tamplate and the problem was that in this tamplate the CSP headers were configured already. So when trying to add CSP in `_Layout` i was not resetting the default implementation. So i just needed to remove `_Layout` CSP and configure default CSP.